# Scala only language with overloaded extractors?

Tags: scala, f#, programming-languages, functional-programming, pattern-matching

In at least some of the ML family languages, you can define records on which you can perform pattern matching e.g. http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses - the basic idea is that you define a record type with named fields, a constructor is automatically created with those fields as parameters so you can create records of that type, and an extractor is automatically created with those fields as parameters so you can pattern match on records of that type.

Scala goes a step further and allows the fields stored in the record, the constructor parameters and the extractor parameters to be decoupled from each other e.g. http://daily-scala.blogspot.com/2009/11/overloaded-unapply.html - in this it is living up to its goal of supporting both object-oriented and functional programming. (Object-oriented languages of course normally allow stored fields and constructor parameters to be decoupled, though they don't normally have extractors.)

Are there any other languages that have pattern matching and allow such decoupling?

Has anything been written about the pros and cons of such decoupling?

Comment: Haskell is a ML family language?

Comment: Never used them, but Haskell views are similar

Comment: And of course, dynamic languages like Scheme allow this without language support, but I don't know if anyone makes use of it

Comment: @Owen Being dynamic doesn't really have anything to do with it. People have written OCaml macros that provide view patterns without requiring support from the language and OCaml is static. Mathematica cannot express this despite being "dynamic".

Comment: @JonHarrop true it is not necessary, but it is one way to do it. (consider eg ruby, R)

Comment: @Owen "it is one way to do it". Are you saying that dynamic typing is one way to do view patterns? If so, I don't understand.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean dynamic typic. I meant dynamic access to variables (ie in R you can write an assignment function because the language itselddoesn't have lvalues)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I admit that I don't have 100% of the background required to understand your question, but I can say that F# has a feature called "[Active Patterns](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Active_Patterns)" that it seems could be used to build the same functionality that your `daily-scala` link demonstrates.

Is that in the neighborhood of what you're looking for?

Answer (score 5):

No, F# also provides that feature.

Examples in the second article can be implemented using [Partial Active Patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233248.aspx):

```ml
let (|String|_|) = function "s" -> Some "yay" | _ -> None
let (|Int|_|) = function 1 -> Some "hmm" | _ -> None

let (|StringList|_|) = function "x" -> Some [1; 2; 3] | _ -> None
let (|IntList|_|) = function 1 -> Some ["one"; "two"] | _ -> None

match 1 with 
| Int s -> printfn "%O" s 
| _ -> printfn "Unmatched"

match "s" with 
| String s -> printfn "%O" s 
| _ -> printfn "Unmatched"

match "x" with 
| StringList [x; y; z] -> printfn "%O" (x, y, z) 
| _ -> printfn "Unmatched"

match 1 with 
| IntList [x; y] -> printfn "%O" (x, y) 
| _ -> printfn "Unmatched"
```

Active Patterns is a powerful technique, you can even write it in a [recursive](http://fsharpnews.blogspot.com/2010/12/parsing-mathematical-expressions-using.html) way. Its combination with pattern matching provides a convenient toolkit for destructuring data. However, pattern matching is inexhaustive so you have to use wildcard(`_`) as the last pattern.

Answer (score 4):

For reference, Don Syme (the inventor of F#) wrote a paper about F#'s "Active Patterns": [Extensible Pattern Matching Via a Lightweight Language Extension – Syme, et al.](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/79947/p29-syme.pdf)

Answer (score 4):

There is a long history of first class patterns in typed functional languages.

In Haskell land, we use the [`-XViewPatterns`](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/ViewPatterns) extension for programmatic patterns.

The first true view patterns go back to Phil Wadler's 1987 paper on [views](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/papers/view/view.ps)